# Finding vector initial point.

Tags: vectors

The Problem: Find the initial point of a non-zero vector $u$ with terminal point $Q(3,0,-5)$ such that $u$ is oppositely directed to $v=(4,-2,-1)$

I am given that the answer is $u=(7,-2,-6)$.

I am confused about the definition of what "oppositely directed" means.
Wouldn't $u=-v=Q-\text{Initial}$? This did not get me the answer.

Comment: Are you sure $u = (7, 2, -6)$ and not $u = (7, -2, -6)$?

Comment: sorry, typo there. any explanation for this?

Comment: Everything you have done is correct. From your equation $$-v = Q - I$$ can you solve for the initial $I$?

Comment: I got $I=(0,2,-4)$ instead, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: my bad calculation error

Comment: Did you get it?

Comment: Yes, managed to get it! thankyou